# Google Bigquery - Compile error in C# at TableRow.FData && j.Query(qr, "PID").Fetch()

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

Hi The below code I am executing for Google BigQuery, I am getting an error message at ".Fetch()" && "TableRow.FData"
Can you please help me regarding this? is that i missed any Reference.

The error message is

```
Error   1   'Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.JobsResource.QueryRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Fetch' and no extension method 'Fetch' accepting a first argument of type 'Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.JobsResource.QueryRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\users\srinivasa\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\p12\p12\Program.cs 71  69  p12
```

Error   2   The type name 'FData' does not exist in the type 'Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableRow'    c:\users\srinivasa\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\p12\p12\Program.cs 75  35  p12

```
  QueryResponse response = j.Query(qr, "XXX").Fetch();
        foreach (TableRow row in response.Rows)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach (TableRow.FData field in row.F)
            {
                list.Add(field.V);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\t", list));
        }
```

Comment: I got the answer @ https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the logic by seeing google documentation @ 
[Querying Data](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data)